# find all dates between startdate and enddate with a gap of certain number of days in php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, date

My task is to find all dates between a start date and end date in such a way that, the dates generated should have a gap of certain number of days.

Lets take start date as `12/01/2014`(MM/DD/YYYY) and end date as `01/05/2015`(MM/DD/YYYY). I need to find all the dates between these dates such that the gap between the dates will be 5. That is the predicted output is:

`12/06/2014, 12/11/2014, 12/16/2014, 12/21/2014, 12/26/2014, 12/31/2014, 01/05/2015`

Can anyone please help me.. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: where are your attempts on making this happen?

Comment: Do you want PHP or javascript? For the vast majority of the world, 01/05/2015 is 1 May, 2015. Is that the date you expect?

Comment: @RobG: no, 01/05/2015 is American month/day/year format; see 2nd table [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php). If date would be separated with `.` or `-` (01.05.2015 or 01-05-2015), then this format would be day/month/year.

Comment: @Glavić—the separator doesn't in indicate the format of the date string. And do you want javascript or PHP?

Comment: @RobG: it doesn't, but PHP will parse date based on format. `01/05/2015` will never be `May 1st, 2015`, but will be `January 5th, 2015`.

Comment: @Glavić—you tagged the question with javascript and PHP. I've asked twice which language you are using to parse the string and you haven't answered. In javascript, parsing of strings is implementation dependent so even if a particular format is parsed correctly by one, it's no indication that all implementations will do the same.

Comment: @RobG: I tagged? This is not my question. And I am talking about php...

Comment: @Glavić—sorry, I assumed (incorrectly) that you were the OP. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$s = new DateTime('12/01/2014');
$e = new DateTime('01/05/2015');

while ($s <= $e) {
    echo $s->format('m/d/Y'), "\n";
    $s->modify('+5 day');
}
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/231486)</kbd>

Comment: I think there's a typo, the comma should be a period right: 
echo $s->format('m/d/Y'). "\n";

But yes I think that works

Comment: @johnjg12 no its not a typo, but a valid syntax for echo

Answer (score 0):

This simple function should do the trick.

```
function get_list($start_date, $end_date, $gap_days) {
    // convert dates to timestamp
    $start_timestamp = strtotime($start_date);
    $end_timestamp = strtotime($end_date);
    $gap_seconds = 24 * 3600 * $gap_days;
    // initialize the output
    $output = array();
    // find all the dates in between, and add them to the output array
    for ($timestamp=$start_timestamp+$gap_seconds; $timestamp<$end_timestamp; $timestamp+=$gap_seconds) {
        $output[] = date("m/d/Y", $timestamp);
    }
    // return the output
    return $output;
}
```

For example, this...

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris");
print_r(get_list("12/01/2014", "01/05/2015", 5));
```

...outputs...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12/06/2014
    [1] => 12/11/2014
    [2] => 12/16/2014
    [3] => 12/21/2014
    [4] => 12/26/2014
    [5] => 12/31/2014
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try using `strtotime()`. Example:

```
function allDates($from,$to){
    $dates = array();
    $start_date = explode('/', $from);
    $end_date = explode('/', $to);
    $start_date = strtotime($start_date[2] . '-' . $start_date[0] . '-' . $start_date[1]);
    $end_date = strtotime($end_date[2] . '-' . $end_date[0] . '-' . $end_date[1]);

    if ($end_date >= $start_date){
        array_push($dates, date('d/m/Y', $start_date));
        while ($start_date < $end_date)
        {
            $start_date += 86400;
            array_push($dates,date('d/m/Y', $start_date));
        }
    }
    return $dates;
}

$allDates = allDates('12/01/2014', '01/05/2015');

print '<pre>';
print_r($allDates);
print '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you'd parse the strings to Dates, then successively add 5 days to the earlier Date until it passes the later date, collecting formatted strings as you go.

You haven't said what format the date strings are, it seems it's m/d/y, which is peculiar to the US and neighbours.

```
// Parse date string in m/d/y format
// Separator can be any non–digit character
function parseMDY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[2], --b[0], b[1]);
}

// Return a date string formatted as m/d/y
function formatDateMDY(d) {
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n}
  return z(d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + z(d.getDate()) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
} 

// Expects dates in m/d/y format
// End should be after start
// Returns an array of date strings
function getDates(start, end, gap) { 
  start = parseMDY(start);
  end = parseMDY(end);
  gap = Number(gap);
  var days = [];

  while (start < end) {
    days.push(formatDateMDY(start));
    start.setDate(start.getDate() + gap);
  }
  return days;
}
```